# LBA-48 only works after going to standby with 250gb ATA/IDE drive

Tags: linux, laptop, ssd, pata, acer-travelmate

I decided to get an SSD for my old Acer TravelMate 662LCI laptop, so i bought [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/M-2-NGFF-SATA-SSD-To-2-5-IDE-PATA-HHD-Converter-Adapter-Card-With-White-Case/321724807185?hash=item4ae84af811:g:wosAAOSwcwhVLMQV) IDE to M.2 adapter and a Western Digital Blue 250GB SSD.

The laptop is currenty running Arch Linux on an external 160GB HDD connected via USB. So I connected the SSD to the laptop and the BIOS correctly showed it. But when i booted i got tons of errors like this:

```
[   39.198156] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[   39.198183] ata1: EH complete
[   39.210263] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[   39.217138] ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x25
[   39.220719] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[   39.224183] ata1.00: cmd 25/00:08:60:59:1c/00:00:1d:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
                    res 51/10:08:60:59:1c/10:00:1d:00:00/e0 Emask 0x81 (invalid argument)
[   39.230747] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[   39.234131] ata1.00: error: { IDNF }
[   39.256732] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[   39.256786] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 488397152
```

I first thought that this sector was just unreadable or corrupted, but when I put the laptop to standby and woke it up again, the SSD worked flawlessly and I could partition it. But after a reboot, the problem appeared again and I could solve it again by putting the laptop to standby and waking it up again. I did a bit of research and tried to find the last sector that doen't give a read error when using `dd` to copy it:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null skip=268435448 count=1 status=progress
```

The sector was number 268435448, which is very near to the CHS limit that is 268435455. So i looked up if my laptop IDE chipset, (which is the Intel 82801DBM (ICH-4) by the way) and BIOS support LBA-48 addressing, but i didn't find anything about it, only a post somewhere suggesting a BIOS update. So i searched and found one from 2008, which is much later than the implementation of LBA-48, and installed it. But the system is still showing the same errors and i can still fix them the same way. I'm thinking about buying a 128 GB SSD and returning this one. But why does the SSD **only** work after going to standby?

Comment: What version of kernel?  uname -r

Comment: Kernel version is 4.13.9-1-ARCH